# MAUI Shell Flyout unwanted click through behavior

Tags: .net, maui

I'm having an issue creating a Shell Flyout for my application.

The flyout has the correct design and work as intended, except for a part : when I open it on my main page, it seems I can click through it on the buttons on the page itself, at the background.

[image: Unwanted shell behavior]

Here's the code for my Shell Flyout :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="UBReferee.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UBReferee"
    xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
    xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:MauiUtils;assembly=MauiUtils"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">
    
    <Shell.FlyoutContent>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <utils:ImageTintColor Grid.Row="0" Source="ub_logo_transparent.svg" Aspect="AspectFit"/>

            <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,50,0,50">
                <utils:ImageTintColor VerticalOptions="Center" Source="brightness.svg" Margin="20,0,20,0"/>
                <Switch x:Name="ThemeSwitch" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
                <utils:ImageTintColor VerticalOptions="Center" Source="dark.svg" Margin="20,0,20,0"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Button Grid.Row="3" Margin="20, 0, 20, 25" Text="{lang:Translate Language}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" ImageSource="translate.svg" Clicked="Lang_Clicked" />
            <Button Grid.Row="4" Margin="20, 0, 20, 25" Text="{lang:Translate Logout}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" ImageSource="logout_2.svg" Clicked="LogOut_Clicked" />
        </Grid>
    </Shell.FlyoutContent>

    <ShellContent
        Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
        Title="Splash"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Splash}"
        Route="Splash">
    </ShellContent>

    <ShellContent        
        Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
         Title="Login"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"
         Route="LoginPage"    
        Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"/>

    <ShellContent
         Title="StageSelectionPage"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:StageSelectionPage}"
         Route="StageSelectionPage"        
        Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"/>

    <ShellContent
        Title="CompetitionPage"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CompetitionPage}"
        Route="CompetitionPage"/>
</Shell>
```

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    ILocalizationResourceManager _localizationResourceManager;

    public AppShell(ILocalizationResourceManager localizationResourceManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _localizationResourceManager = localizationResourceManager;

        // (A few routes registred...)

        ThemeSwitch.IsToggled = AppCore.Instance.CurrentThemeDark();
        AppCore.Instance.ApplyTheme();


        //this.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Disabled;
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        //on empêche de se promener dans le stack vers l'arrière
        return true;
    }

    private void LogOut_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowPopup(
            new DialogPopup(
                () => {
                    var _ = AppCore.Instance.LogOut();
                },
                null,
                _localizationResourceManager.GetValue("Logout"),
                "road_sign_warning.svg",
                _localizationResourceManager.GetValue("LogoutMessage"),
                true,
                _localizationResourceManager.GetValue("BtnYes"),
                _localizationResourceManager.GetValue("BtnNo")
            )
        );
    }

    private void UpdateLang(string lang)
    {
        switch (lang)
        {
            case "English":
                _localizationResourceManager.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
                break;
            case "Français":
                _localizationResourceManager.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Lang_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowPopup(new ListPopup(new List<string>() { "English", "Français" }, UpdateLang, _localizationResourceManager.GetValue("Language"), ""));
    }

    private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        AppCore.Instance.SetTheme(e.Value);
    }
}
```

The command bound to the different buttons are very basic (only a matter of `GoToAsync`), I don't think they're the cause of this behavior, but I can add them as well  if needed.

Comment: I tested the code you provided. This is a bug on `Shell.FlyoutContent` and It is recommended to report it on [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, it seems to be a bug in MAUI.

We found a workaround : adding to the flyout an ImageButton covering the whole flyout, with no background and no clicked event, so the "background button" eats all the clicked events before they reach the buttons behind the background.